# graph in R with grouping letters from the Tukey, LSD, Duncan test with agricolae package

Tags: r, tukey

I would like to produce the attached graph

[image]

with the R package agricolae, could someone give me an example with the attached data?

[image]

I expect an adapted graph with the data

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Loop Vinyl! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to change to a long data format

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(TREAT = c(rep('t1', 4), rep('t2', 4), rep('t3', 4), rep('t4', 4), rep('t5', 4)), 
                 REP = c(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4),5)), 
                 VAR1 = c(16.10, 14.10, 5.8, 4.90, 30.80, 29.00, 28.80, 16.60, 31.30, 29.60, 28.10, 19.50, 21.45, 23.60, 25.95, 28.55, 27.70, 13.70, 8.10, 0.00), 
                 VAR2 = c(0.81, 0.71, 0.29, 0.25, 1.54, 1.45, 1.44, 0.83, 1.57, 1.48, 1.41, 0.98, 1.07, 1.18, 1.30, 1.43, 1.37, 0.96, 0.41, 0.00), 
                 VAR3 = c(0.97, 0.85, 0.35, 0.29, 1.85, 1.74, 1.73, 1.00, 1.88, 1.78, 1.69, 1.17, 1.29, 1.42, 1.56, 1.71, 1.64, 0.82, 0.49, 0.00), 
                 VAR4 = c(1.45, 1.27, 0.52, 0.44, 2.77, 2.61, 2.59, 1.49, 2.82, 2.66, 2.53, 1.76, 1.93, 2.12, 2.34, 2.57, 2.46, .123, 0.73, 0.00)
                 ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(VAR1:VAR4, 
               names_to = 'VAR')
ggplot(data = df, 
       mapping = aes(x = VAR, 
                     y = value, 
                     fill = TREAT)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(x = 'Apparent recovery efficiency', 
       y = 'Aboveground biomass cut')
```

Once you calculate, can use geom_errorbar() to add the bars.
[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks, and how do I add the letters of the Tukery test grouping to the graph?

Comment: You will need to add a geom_text() layer to your plot is add the Tukey groupings ( I think you mean Tukey, I am not familiar with Tukery).

Comment: Yes, Tukey Test

Comment: how do I add geom_text() layer to your plot is add the Tukey groupings ?

Comment: You will need to calculate them first. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/08/how-to-perform-tukey-hsd-test-in-r/, then add + geom_text() with the mapping of the label generated from the Tukey testing. Given the data you have provided, I think I have answered your initial questions. If you are not able to follow the guidance for the additional calculations, you may consider accepting my response to your initial plotting question and using my example code to ask targeted follow-up questions in a new post. with a tag for TukeyHSD.

Comment: library(agricolae)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.table("vermiwash.txt", header = TRUE)
head(data)
View(data)

# Create a bar plot using ggplot2
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = CUT, y = VAR1, fill = TREAT, group = TREAT)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", width=0.7) +
  labs(title="Bar Plot for Data", y="Value", x="CUT") +
  theme_minimal()

print(plot)

Comment: ###

#com a variável 1
model_var1<-aov(VAR1~TREAT, data=data)
summary(model_var1)
cv.model(model_var1)


#
#var1
tukey_var1 <- HSD.test(model_var1, c("TREAT"), main="VAR1 ~ TREAT*CUT", console=TRUE)
head(tukey_var1)